# LINQ doesn't give me correct data

Tags: .net, linq

The following SQL script returns 2 rows from my database:

```
SELECT ChaperoneID, Name 
FROM ChaperoneInfo 
WHERE ChaperoneID IN (SELECT ChaperoneID 
                      FROM ChaperoneMatches 
                      WHERE DriverID = '111')
```

The following LINQ code gives me an empty list:

```
...
private const string SQL_GET_CHAPERONES_NAME = "SELECT ChaperoneID, Name FROM ChaperoneInfo WHERE ChaperoneID IN (SELECT ChaperoneID FROM ChaperoneMatches WHERE DriverID = '{0}')";
    ....
public List<ChaperoneNames> GetChaperones(string driverID)
{
    List<ChaperoneNames> diList = new List<ChaperoneNames>();
    ISafeDataContext dc = new ISafeDataContext();

    try
    {
        string strSQL = SQL_GET_CHAPERONES_NAME;
        object[] objParameters = new object[] { driverID };
        diList = dc.ExecuteQuery<ChaperoneNames>(strSQL, objParameters).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("iSafe", ex.StackTrace + "\n \n" + ex.Message);
    }

    return diList;
}
```

where

```
public class ChaperoneNames
{
        public string ChaperoneID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is it something in the names of the `ChaperoneNames` fields?

Comment: Not totally sure, but I think it's the '' around your param in SQL_GET_CHAPERONES_NAME statement. AFAIK this is done automatically for string data types.

Comment: Are you shure that you call GetChaperones with value '111'?

Comment: Yes, ChaperoneID is nvarchar(50), so '111' is a valid value.  Again, as a plain SQL statement, I get a valid response.

Comment: LINQ is too widespread to consider it broken to the point of "not giving correct data". Does your code fire an exception? What is an ISafeDataContext? If you use a plain datareader, does the query return any rows?

Comment: OK, let's go with "doesn't give expected data".  There is no exception fired, diList is simply an empty list.

Comment: Does this even count as LINQ?

Comment: @Anthony not really, unless ISafeDataContext is doing something exotic.

Comment: @AharonManne at this point, I think you need to examine what's going on in ISafeDataContext.ExecuteQuery. Can you update your question with that method's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ExecuteQuery command will attempt to use sql parameters which means your line

```
private const string SQL_GET_CHAPERONES_NAME = "SELECT ChaperoneID, Name FROM ChaperoneInfo WHERE ChaperoneID IN (SELECT ChaperoneID FROM ChaperoneMatches WHERE DriverID = '{0}')";
```

will product TSQL, something like

```
 DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = '111'
 SELECT ChaperoneID, Name FROM ChaperoneInfo WHERE ChaperoneID IN 
    (SELECT ChaperoneID FROM ChaperoneMatches WHERE DriverID = '@p0')"
```

What you need to do is remove the quotes, ie

```
private const string SQL_GET_CHAPERONES_NAME = "SELECT ChaperoneID, Name FROM ChaperoneInfo WHERE ChaperoneID IN (SELECT ChaperoneID FROM ChaperoneMatches WHERE DriverID = {0})";
```

so your query becomes something like

```
 DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = '111'
 SELECT ChaperoneID, Name FROM ChaperoneInfo WHERE ChaperoneID IN 
    (SELECT ChaperoneID FROM ChaperoneMatches WHERE DriverID = @p0)"
```